# Override style of an external library from our component angular

Tags: css, angular, angular8

I am using an external panel component which would open on a button click.It has default width and other style properties.Is there any way I can override the width of the panel and used as responsive one .what i want to achieve is programmatically change the width of the panel in my components .
For example,
In my app.component.html iam using the panel container inside app.component.html

```
panel-container
```

How can i attach a custom class
   panel-container class 
         ="panel-width"

In.css
        .panel-width{
         Width:500 px
          }

Without changing angular default view encapsultion

Answer (score 8):

You can use `:host::ng-deep` to style the external component.

```
:host::ng-deep .panel-container {
  width: 500px;
}
```

It is deprecated since 2017, but there is no new way to do this if you do not want to change ViewEncapsulation. Source: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: please do avoid the `::ng-deep`.  Referring to my answer, it will avoid any deprecate in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Got the solution.
We can override the same in our parent CSS file itself.
Dont use ng deep as that s deprecated

Answer (score -1):

**Overwriting library styles in separate global styles — not scoped!**

let's override the Angular Material tab style.

1. create angular material tab scss file in `app > assets > scss > override > am_tab.scss`
2. and import the am_tab.scss file in the styles.scss `@import 'assets/scss/override/am_tab.scss'`

   ```
   // am_tab.scss

   mat-tab-group {
     &.mat-tab-group.mat- primary .mat-ink-bar {
       background-color: red;
     }
   }
   ```

More read in this [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/best-way-to-overwrite-angular-materials-styles-e38dc8b84962)